# override --fail-fast in rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, continuous-integration

I run specs in my local machine and in a CI server. In the first case I want specs to fail fast, and in the other I want run all of them. I've set `--fail-fast` in my `.rspec` file. How can I override it on the CI server? I run there RSpec using `rake spec` and I set `SPEC_OPTS` env variable.

Comment: Have you considered not checking the .rspec file in ? (or removing it on the CI server before running specs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest answer is to remove `.rspec` from your repo. It is used only by you and any other contributor don't need to see that you are using [NyanCat](https://github.com/mattsears/nyan-cat-formatter) to see how your test's are doing.

Comment: Is there a `--no-fail-fast` option? Removing `.rspec` is too much.

Comment: I don't know. But you can do not include `--fail-fast` in `.rspec`.

Comment: Many years later, there is the --no-fail-fast. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/fail-fast-option#using-%60--no-fail-fast%60

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `.rspec` file in your home directory so that the settings only apply to your local machine, and then the `.rspec` in the project directory will override any settings there.

Answer (score 0):

`--no-fail-fast` has since been added.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/fail-fast-option#using-%60--no-fail-fast%60